# how to create a video of scrolling credits (text) with iOS AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, video, text, avfoundation, image

I'm currently looking for options to how I might be able to create a video of scrolling text using AVFoundation.

The scrolling text could be just a few lines of strings but it must be pieced together to form a video.

Could I get a rough direction on how I might be able to achieve that?

Comment: You could render the animation to a series of images and write these to a MOV/MP4 using AVAssetWriter. The rendering is up to you. You could use CoreGraphics along with CoreAnimation, or you could use OpenGL.